# Can okhttp3.internal.http2.StreamResetException: stream was reset: INTERNAL_ERROR be caused by API call limit?

Tags: android, retrofit2

I'm using Retrofit to request data from a websites API which has a limit of 50calls/minute (varies) but I'm repeatedly getting this error:

```
okhttp3.internal.http2.StreamResetException: stream was reset: INTERNAL_ERROR
```

Is it possible that I'm getting this error because I'm reaching that call limit which varies?

Comment: Did you check my answer?

Comment: yeah, but I'm still getting the error

Answer (score 0):

**This is a server error after the headers are sent.**

You should restricting the request to use HTTP 1 like this :

**JAVA :**

```
OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder(); 
okHttpClient.setProtocols(Arrays.asList(Protocol.HTTP_1_1));
```

**KOTLIN:**

```
OkHttpClient().also {
        it.protocols().add(Protocol.HTTP_1_1)
 }
```